# Excel Application.ontime macro re-opens workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is using some macros to automatically close it after some idle time elapses.
There is 1 issue, if the user has other excel workbooks (regardless if its xlsx or xlsm) after the procedure for it to close the target file. it REOPENS the target file again and can continue in a loop like this until the user closes all of their open workbooks quitting the application.

any advice on how to tweak this code so that the Application.OnTime events will stop effectively when the target workbook has closed would be appreciated.

The goal was simple:
If a user leaves their desk, or they are working on another workbook and they forget to close the file it will save and close the workbook and only that workbook without disrupting any other function or workbook

this does work fine on its own only if and only if the workbook that has this code is the only book open in the application.

In "Thisworkbook" I have below

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call StopTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
End Sub
```

In a separate module I have below:

```vb
Dim DownTime As Date

Sub SetTimer()
    DownTime = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
        Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
        Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub ShutDown()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With Workbooks("Customer Complaint Tracker.xlsm")
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried using a different method to run a timer which I think worked on windows timing instead of the application itself but I could not get it to function.

Comment: When you `SetTimer` - before creating the new `.OnTime` you need to remove the old one. That way there is only ever one in memory. Also, when running `ShutDown()` (or when user closes workbook manually) you need to remove the next (and only) time stored in the schedule.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me, but I am not a master of VBA syntax yet. would I accomplish what your explaining by changing 'SetTimer' Schedule from True to False?

Comment: if you always call `StopTimer` before `SetTimer`, you can just add `StopTimer` as the first line in `SetTimer`.  And add a call to `StopTimer` in `ShutDown`.

Comment: Tim, your suggestion works! I had it tested from another user simulating work scenario, and it closed without reopening i appreciate it! I didn't think it needed the call each other's subs to break the chain. first time poster so is there a "solved" flag?

Comment: You can post your revised code as an answer and accept it.